# Moving an image

Tags: html, css, move

I want to move an image downward . but i cant when i use top or bottom the image moves right or left .
(i dont know how but i managed to make it like a layer mask in photoshop!)
i used margin , padding , top , bottom etc but none of them worked
here is my code

```css
.header {
    
    height: 200px;
    background: #313b3d url(https://preview.ibb.co/mFmpK5/grotti_canyon_wallpaper_1366x768.jpg)no-repeat 160px top;  
}

.head-right a {
    color: #fff;
}

.head-right a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

.head-right h1 {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 17px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    font-size: 28px;
    text-align: center;
    background: url() no-repeat center top;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
 <div class="head-wrp">
  <div class="head-right">
   <h1><a href="(*link*)">(*title*)</a></h1>
   <h2>(*short_description*)</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="head-left">
   <box:menu>
    <ul>
     <view:menu>
      <li class="(*menu_item_selected*)">
       <a href="(*menu_item_link*)">(*menu_item_title*)</a>
      </li>
     </view:menu>
    </ul>
   </box:menu>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because you are using the background property to define the image, then you'll have to use css `background-position`

```css
.header {
    
    height: 200px;
    background: #313b3d url(https://preview.ibb.co/mFmpK5/grotti_canyon_wallpaper_1366x768.jpg)no-repeat; 
    background-position: 0 50px;
}

.head-right a {
    color: #fff;
}

.head-right a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

.head-right h1 {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 17px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    font-size: 28px;
    text-align: center;
    background: url() no-repeat center top;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
 <div class="head-wrp">
  <div class="head-right">
   <h1><a >(*title*)</a></h1>
   <h2>(*short_description*)</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="head-left">
   <box:menu>
    <ul>
     <view:menu>
      <li class="(*menu_item_selected*)">
       <a >(*menu_item_title*)</a>
      </li>
     </view:menu>
    </ul>
   </box:menu>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```